# How can I tell typescript that the getAssociation function exists in a Sequelize model?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface TableBAttributes {
    TableBId: number;
}

interface TableAAttributes {
    TableAId: number;
    TableB: TableB;
}

class TableA extends Model<TableAAttributes> {}
TableA.init({
   TableAId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
   },
   TableB: {
      DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
         model: TableB,
         key: 'tableB_id'
      },
      field: 'tableB_id'
   }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'TableA',
  tableName: 'TableA'
});

TableA.belongsTo(TableB, {
   foreignKey: 'tableB_id',
   as: 'TableB'
});

class TableB extends Model<TableBAttributes> {};
TableB.init({
    TableBId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
}, {
   sequelize,
   modelName: 'TableB',
   tableName: 'TableB'
});

(async () => {
   const test = await TableA.findByPk(1);
   const relatedTableB = await test.getTableB();
   console.log(relatedTableB);
})();
```

If I run this code, everything works correctly, and I get back the associated `TableB` from my query. My only problem is, that typescript complains that the `test.getTableB()` function does not exist, as this method is created by Sequelize.

How could I tell typescript that this method exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this if it works for you.

For more [info](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html)

```js
import {
  Model,
  HasOneGetAssociationMixin,
} from "sequelize";

interface TableBAttributes {
  TableBId: number;
}

interface TableAAttributes {
  TableAId: number;
}

class TableA extends Model<TableAAttributes> {
  public getTableB!: HasOneGetAssociationMixin<TableB>
}

class TableB extends Model<TableBAttributes> { }

TableA.belongsTo(TableB, {
  foreignKey: 'tableB_id',
  as: 'TableB'
});

(async () => {
  const test = await TableA.findByPk(1);
  const relatedTableB = await test.getTableB();
  console.log(relatedTableB);
})();
```